# trouble with declaring a delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

i have two views with view1 calling view2. i need to pass data from view2 back to view1. so i am attempting to set up a delegate. here's what i got in view controller 2:

```
.h file

@protocol addEventDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) setAddedEventFlag:(BOOL) hasAddedEvent;

@end

@interface AddEventViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) id delegate;  //changed from strong to weak
```

i then @synthesize delegate in the .m file

when try to include the addEventDelegate for the first view controller, xcode can not find it:

```
.h file

#import "AddEventViewController.h"

@interface FieldReportViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, 
UITextViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, addEventDelegate>
```

i get the error: "Cannot find protocol declaration for 'addEventDelegate'".

what is wrong?

EDIT:

[image]

//code

[image]

ERRORS:

[image]

Comment: Your error message says `addEventDelegat` -- are you sure it's spelled correctly in your code?

Comment: Some other notes: 1) delegates shouldn't be retained; you should use `weak` or `assign` for the property; 2) If you're expecting the delegate to follow the protocol, it should be declared there too `id<addEventDelegate> delegate`; 3) I'm pretty sure you don't want `<NSObject>` in the protocol definition -- are you sure you need that?

Comment: yes, i'm sry, i just typo'ed it. it is 'addEventDelegate'

Comment: Could this be an import loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. i had an #import loop. I was #importing all my classes in my .h files. i changed to @Class in .h file and moved the #import's to the .m files and works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your spelling is correct.
2. Make sure that AddEventViewController.h/.m are added to the project.

Other than that, what you have is fine.

***Edit***

Something else I would suggest is to rename your delegate, perhaps there is a naming conflict.  Although I haven't seen any issues with 'add' and 'set', but I've seen issues in the past when prefixing with, say, 'new'.

Also, clean your project, and rebuild and see if that helps.

There could be a situation if you have multiple targets in your project, and possibly only added AddEventViewController.h/m to one of them, and you are building/debugging a different target.

Comment: spelling correct (when adding the delegate to FieldReportViewController, it autocompletes). AddEvetnViewController.h/.m files are included, the app compiles and runs fine w/out this error.

Comment: sadly, no. i checked those things before i posted. this is the first time trying to use delegates.

Comment: What happens if you add a forward declaration:   `@protocol addEventDelegate;` at the top of the FieldReportViewController.m file under the `#include "AddEventViewController.h"`?

Comment: well, my #import "AddEventViewController.h" is in my FieldEventViewController.h; i tried added the @protocol addEventDelegate in the .h and .m file, didn't work.

Comment: Sounds like an environmental issue.  You using xCode?

Comment: Do you have multiple targets in your project?

Comment: the main <projectName> and <projectName>Tests.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct way to define a protocol

```
@protocol addEventDelegate; // forward declaration for delegate property

@interface AddEventViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    id <addEventDelegate> *delegate
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <addEventDelegate> *delegate; 

@end // interface

@protocol addEventDelegate <NSObject>
// @optional // if you want to make it optional
    -(void) setAddedEventFlag:(BOOL) hasAddedEvent;
@end // protocol
```

Comment: set it up like this and error still happens. added screen shots to original post.

Comment: Is the file name correct in #import "AddEventViewController.h" ? Or should it be #import "addEventViewController.h" ?

Comment: it is #import "AddEventViewController.h". if i take out the delegate code, my project compiles and runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can import `addEventDelegate` in `FieldReportViewController.m` file

```
@interface FieldReportViewController ()<AddEventDelegate>
@end
```

This one is working in my app